# What SQL server 2012 edition to use for database size which is 13GB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What SQL server 2012 edition to use for database size which is 13GB...we were using express edition earlier. Now that we have merged all individual database into one, we want to upgrade out beta server. Kindly suggest. Should we go only for entreprise edition or can we use developer or standard edition considering the cost.

Answer (score 1):

A developer edition cannot be used in production due to obvious reasons. Your next choices are Web, Standard, Enterprise - in order of costs. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) a comparison between editions you can take a look at.